# Check how many data points are inputed by user before adding them to array to avoid index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Check how many data points are inputed by user before adding them to array to avoid index out of bounds exception
How would i check before adding to array?

```
    while (userInput>MAX) {
        System.out.println("Amount of numbers too large. Input number less than 50.");
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of numbers that are in this data set: ");
        userInput = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    int numIntegers = userInput;

    //have the user input the numbers delineated by a space
    System.out.println("Enter each number separated by a space:");
    int[] integerArray = new int[numIntegers];
    
    for(int index=0;index<MAX;index++){
        integerArray[index] =  scanner.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you are asking for a piece of code to be written. That will usually not attract a lot of readers and positive feedback. Think if you can rephrase this as a problem that people find interesting and easy to search for.

Comment: If you don't want to ask how many in advance, then you MUST use an expandable data structure like an `ArrayList<Integer>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before creating the array it would be better to ask user how many data points he wants to enter then creating the array.

**simple example**

```
System.out.println("How many data points : ");
int ele = input.nextInt();
}

 double [] dataPoints = new double[ele];
```

If u want to fill array to avoid **index out of bounds exception**

```
 for(int i=0;i<ele;i++){
               dataPoints[i] = input.nextDouble();
            }
```

Fixing your code

```
  while (userInput>MAX) {
        System.out.println("Amount of numbers too large. Input number less than 50.");
        System.out.println("Enter the amount of numbers that are in this data set: ");
        userInput = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    int numIntegers = userInput;

    //have the user input the numbers delineated by a space
    System.out.println("Enter each number separated by a space:");
    int[] integerArray = new int[numIntegers];
    
    for(int index=0;index<numIntegers;index++){
        integerArray[index] =  scanner.nextInt();
    }
```

Comment: coudn't figure out how to add all the code. Just figured it out and added the code that i have

Comment: change max with numIntegers .  for(int index=0;index<numIntegers;index++){,..

Comment: i could just do a while loop and keep asking until the array.length size equals the user number input but id rather have it do it in one line

Comment: u could do that with a for loop for(int i=0;i<numIntegers;i++){ then filling the array as i mention on the code that i wrote.